# candidate template ignored: substitution failure(error with clang but not g++)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, clang

I have a problem of substitution failure, and answers of some similar questions do not help me.

Here is the code:

```
template<int dim, int loop>  
class Reference{
public:
   //...
   template<int r, int c> using matrix_t = int[r][c];
   Reference(const matrix_t<dim, loop> &mat){}
}; 

template<int dim, int loop>
class Partition{
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    template<int r, int c> using matrix = int[r][c];
    template<int r, int c> void readPattern(const matrix<r,c> &pattern)
    {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

And I call this template function like so:

```
int main()
{
   // ... 
   const int DENOISE_UR[3][4] = {/*...*/};
   Partition<1,2> partition;
   partition.readPattern(DENOISE_UR);
   // ...
}
```

Using g++, it compiles.

When using clang++(linux) to compile(`clang++ -std=c++11 xxx.cpp`), it resulted in the following compiling error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'readPattern'
   note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure[ with r = 3, c = 4 ]
         template<int r, int c> void readPattern(const matrix<r,c> &pattern)
```

Why?

Comment: oO if you remove the definition of `Reference`, [it compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xx2K1gu0J4PFutiP)...

Comment: @Columbo  That's exactly what the problem is. I need to use the class `Reference` in class `Partition`

Comment: @Columbo Change the first alias template to `long[r][c]`: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0DHbcs3C0dm9H3gX ò.Ó

Comment: @dyp Or compare [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/brWQnGkHvnOu629a) and [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wFz1gyxVAFx7C1gg)

Comment: @JorenHeit Yes, but it was not the bug. I've fixed the `namespace` bug, but error still exits. So I've extracted out the problem as above.

Comment: @Columbo Why is it so weird to move the second alias template to the head of file to make it work?

Comment: @Shindou seems like a bug...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug in clang; it misbehaves when an alias template defining an array type is defined within a class template. In fact it can be exploited to [crash the compiler](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24212):

```
template<int I>
struct S {
  template<int J> using T = int[J];
  using U = T<I>;
};
S<3>::U a;
```

Since in your case `Reference::matrix_t` does not depend on the template arguments to `Reference`, the simplest workaround would be to move the definition of `matrix_t` to namespace scope:

```
namespace impl { template<int r, int c> using matrix_t = int[r][c]; }
// ...
template<int dim, int loop>  
class Reference {
  //...
  template<int r, int c> using matrix_t = impl::matrix_t<r, c>;
```

In fact, you don't even need to *use* `impl::matrix_t` to workaround the bug:

```
namespace magic { template<int r, int c> using unused = int[r][c]; } // Huh?
// ...
template<int dim, int loop>  
class Reference {
  //...
  template<int r, int c> using matrix_t = int[r][c]; // Look ma, no hands!
```

---

This is [now fixed](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=243093) (the fix should be in clang release version 3.8.0):

> [AST] Perform additional canonicalization for DependentSizedArrayType
>
> We treated DependentSizedArrayTypes with the same element type but
>   differing size expressions as equivalently canonical.  This would lead
>   to bizarre behavior during template instantiation.
>
> This fixes PR24212.

Comment: Yeah...Just adding the irrelevant `namespace magic` will workaround the bug...I'm sorry I'm not quite well with English, but what does 'Look ma, no hands' mean?

Comment: @Shindou my very wild guess would be that clang ends up with a dangling reference to an alias template, and adding the `namespace magic` ensures that the dangling reference points to something. "Look ma, no hands" is a joke - it's what you say when you're riding a bicycle and take your hands off the handlebars. :)